# Duplicate bean conflicts during integration tests (multiple, merged contexts?, re: surefire vs failsafe?)

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven-3, integration-testing, applicationcontext

I am experiencing some dependency injection errors during the integration-test phase of my application.  I think it's happening because spring is firing up a context during unit testing, then caching all my mock bean instances used for unit tests, which then conflict with the beans fired up during the integration-test phase, causing DI in my classes to fail because Spring is finding multiple instances of the same beans (mock vs real instances).

Note: This issue is only present during the integration-test phase of the app.  The app otherwise starts, runs, and unit tests normally (it's a webapp and I run it with maven 3 using the tomcat:run-war goal).

This is the basic composition of my integration tests.  I wrote a bogus one yesterday just to try and isolate the issue (no DI involved in this test):

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(locations="file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
   @DirtiesContext
    public class ITNonsenseTest {


        @Test
        public void doNothing() {

            System.out.println("hello, world");
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

My integration tests all begin with the prefix "IT" and my unit tests all begin with the prefix "UT"

I am using apache surefire for unit tests, and apache failsafe for integration tests:

from my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.nfire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/UT*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <skipTests>
            ${skipUnitTests}
        </skipTests>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.nfire.plugin.version}</version>
</plugin>
<!-- For Integration Tests -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.nfire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/IT*.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/UT*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <skipTests>
            ${skipIntegrationTests}
        </skipTests>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Even when running my simple ITNonsenseTest above, the Spring context fails to initialize properly.  Since many of the beans I'm trying to create already exist in the context (as mock bean instances from my Unit test phase), Spring is complaining about duplicates being found.

Is there a way to tear down the context after the unit test phase, and build a new context for the integration-test phase?  Or am I just doing something completely wrong?

This is my root-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="file://${conf.dir}/*.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.models, com.myapp.dao, com.myapp.service" />

    <beans:import resource="simplesm-context.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="datasources.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="rabbit-context.xml" />

    <util:properties id="swaggerProps" location="classpath:swagger.properties" />
    <util:properties id="encryptionProps" location="classpath:sharedEncryption.properties" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <beans:bean name="cacheManager" class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCacheManager">
        <beans:property name="caches">
            <beans:set>
                <beans:bean class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache">
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="cache" index="0" ref="defaultCache" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="expiration" index="1" value="86400" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg name="allowClear" index="2" value="false" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:set>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean name="defaultCache" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
        <!--  <beans:property name="cacheName" value="defaultCache" /> -->
        <beans:property name="cacheClientFactory">
            <beans:bean name="cacheClientFactory" class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.spymemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="addressProvider">
            <beans:bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
                <beans:property name="address" value="${ureg.memcached.url}:${ureg.memcached.port}" /> 
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="configuration">
            <beans:bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
                <beans:property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

This is my project's dependencies' versioning info:

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.amqp.version>1.3.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.amqp.version>
    <org.springframework.data.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
    <google.simple.spring.memcached.version>3.2.1</google.simple.spring.memcached.version>
    <maven.nfire.plugin.version>2.17</maven.nfire.plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Lastly, I tried adding a @DirtiesContext to all of my Unit tests that use SpringJunit4ClassRunner, but I'm still seeing this error.  All of my unit tests are structured in the following manner:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@DirtiesContext
public class UTAdditionalDataPointsServiceTest {

    @Configuration
    static class AdditionalDataPointsServiceUnitTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("props")
        public Properties getProperties() {
            return Mockito.mock(Properties.class);
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("npJdbcTemplate")
        public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
            return Mockito.mock(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.class);
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("uJdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
            return Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public AdditionalDataPointsDao getAdditionalDataPointsDao() {
            return Mockito.mock(AdditionalDataPointsDaoImpl.class); 
        }

        @Bean
        public AdditionalDataPointService getAdditionalDataPointService() {
            return Mockito.mock(AdditionalDataPointServiceImpl.class);  
        }

    }

    @Inject
    AdditionalDataPointService adpService;

    @Test
    public void testGetAdditionalDataPoints() throws Exception {
        List<AdditionalDataPoint> adpList = adpService.getAdditionalDataPoints(1); 
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(adpList);
    }
```

I'm fairly confident the issue is the mock instances cached in the context during the unit testing phase, because if i comment out the definition for a bean when theyre instantiated in my root-context.xml file, the errors for those duplicates go away.

The stack traces are always the same, along the lines of:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Properties] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: realInstanceBeanName,mockInstanceBeanNameGetter
```

Comment: First it looks like you didn't read the docs neither maven-surefire-plugin nor of maven-failsafe-plugin cause the include/excludes having good defaults which you should follow. Cause parts of your include/exclude definition is the default like [includes for maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes)

Comment: Many years later I do experience the same for Micronaut framework. Did you find the solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring `classesDirectory` do the job for me. See [Maven-failsafe-plugin fails to execute integration tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254)

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```